# How to change a sound playing start time in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, time, audio

I would like to play a sound in Objective-C with a millisecond start time. I know it is possible this way but "currentTime" only takes seconds:

```
currentPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
currentPlayer.currentTime = 100;
```

Is there a way to set the start time with milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `currentTime` property of `AVAudioPlayer` is an `NSTimeInterval`, which is just a `double`. In other words it's a floating-point value.

This means you can specify fractions of seconds:

```
currentPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
currentPlayer.currentTime = 100.052;
```

Comment: Thank you. I was mistaken becauseof the Apple documentation:  
"The playback point, in seconds, within the timeline of the sound associated with the audio player."